# AWS EventBridge event, access EMR Cluster State Change value for custom input transformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr, aws-event-bridge

I have a Event rule to intercept when an EMR job fails, I am trying to create a custom message using an input transformer and I would like to print out the value for *$.detail.stateChangeReason*

If I look at the Sample Event for the EMR Cluster State Change it looks like:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "8535abb0-f87e-4640-b7b6-8de000dfc30a",
  "detail-type": "EMR Cluster State Change",
  "source": "aws.emr",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2016-12-16T21:00:23Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "severity": "INFO",
    "stateChangeReason": "{\"code\":\"USER_REQUEST\",\"message\":\"Terminated by user request\"}",
    "name": "Development Cluster",
    "clusterId": "j-1YONHTCP3YZKC",
    "state": "TERMINATED",
    "message": "Amazon EMR Cluster j-1YONHTCP3YZKC (Development Cluster) has terminated at 2016-12-16 21:00 UTC with a reason of USER_REQUEST."
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to access that *detail.stateChangeReason.code* and *detail.stateChangeReason.message*
I've tried to use an input path like

```
{"code":"$.detail.stateChangeReason.code","message":"$.detail.stateChangeReason.message"}
```

or like

```
{"reason":"$.detail.stateChangeReason"}
```

but when I try to include them in my template with

```
EMR Failure caused by
"<code>"
"<message>"
"<reason>"
```

I don't get any mail at all. I know it usually works because instead of those values I usually use the value for detail.message in the template, and it works fine.

How can I include those values in my template?

Answer (score 0):

```
  MyRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties: 
      Description: <your_description>
      Name: MyRule
      EventPattern: <your_pattern>
      Targets:
      - Arn: <targetarn>
        Id: MyRule
        InputTransformer:
          InputPathsMap:
            "message": "$.detail.stateChangeReason.message"
            "code" : "$.detail.stateChangeReason.code"
          InputTemplate: |
            {
              "message": <message>,
              "code": <code>
            }
        RetryPolicy:
          MaximumRetryAttempts: 4
          MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 400
```

The value under InputTemplate parameter should remain as is. let us know if it worked :)